# Visual Studio 2019: System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow errors in .NET Core projects

Tags: crash, ide, visual-studio-2019

Hoping someone might be able to assist me with this.

I've been having an issue with Visual Studio where parts of the background processes are constantly crashing and throwing exceptions.

To re-create it I just simply create a new .NET 5 console project, and open it and this is what I am greeted with:

```
StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, Version=4.6.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

I get these windows appearing constantly. If I clear and rebuild solution they come back.
[image]

I am currently on Enterprise 16.11.5 (latest as of this post).
I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling, repairing, disabling extensions, different solutions etc etc but nothing seems to get rid of it or fix it.

Anyone got any ideas?
Also the stack trace for the screenshot below is essentially the above snippet, but there is more if needed once I find out how to attach files.

Comment: Microsoft were unable to resolve this error, I re-installed windows and it seems to have disappeared so closing this off.

Answer (score 0):

Although not technically what I would classify as a solution, reinstalling windows did resolve the error.